# override config map in helm chart during azure devops deploy

Tags: azure-devops, devops, kubernetes-helm

We are using helm charts templates for deployment to kube and Azure devops for CI/CD.in my values.yaml **data** in below section will change as per environment and saved as config map in pod.
**My question is how can I update it during deployment in azure pipeline. We are using Helm upgrade task OR any other way to handle it better.**

```
environment:
    enabled: true
    env:
      enabled: false
    internalConfigMap:
      enabled: true
      **data:
        AZ_DIRECTORY: xxx
        MODEL_ID_SVM: xxx
        MODEL_ID_MULTI: xxx
        MODEL_THRESHOLD_SVM: 'xx'
        SINGLE_ACC_ENDPT: 'xx'
        MODEL_WT_SVM: 'xx'**
```

here is deployment task:(ignore indentation)

```
task: HelmDeploy@0
     displayName: Helm upgrade
                inputs:
                  command: upgrade
                  chartType: Name
                  chartName: chart/$(chartname)
                  releaseName: $(chartname)-${{ parameters.CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG }}
                  namespace: $(NAMESPACE)
                  connectionType: Azure Resource Manager
                  #azureSubscriptionEndpoint: ${{ variables.AZ_SUBSCRIPTION }}
                  #azureResourceGroup: $(AKS_RESOURCE_GROUP)
                # kubernetesCluster: $(K8S_CLUSTER)
                  install: true
                  waitForExecution: true
                  useClusterAdmin: true
                  overrideValues: |
                    template.image.tag=$(imagetag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1: One value file per environment

If you have one `values.yaml` per environment (`environment1-values.yaml`, `environment2-values.yaml` etc) you can refer to different files for each stage in your pipeline.

[The `Helm Upgrade` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/helm-deploy?view=azure-devops#upgrade-command) accepts the parameter `valueFile` which you can use to point to the correct `values.yaml` for the environment you are deploying to

> (Optional) Specify values in a YAML file or a URL. For example,
> specifying myvalues.yaml will result in helm install
> --values=myvals.yaml

## Option 2: Override values on deployment

[The `Helm Upgrade` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/helm-deploy?view=azure-devops#upgrade-command) accepts the parameter `overrideValues` by which you can pass values directly to helm:

> (Optional) Set values on the command line. You can specify multiple
> values by separating values with commas. For example,
> key1=val1,key2=val2. You can also specify multiple values by
> delimiting them with newline as so: key1=val1 key2=val2 Please note
> that if you have a value which itself contains newlines, use the
> valueFile option, else the task will treat the newline as a delimiter.
> The task will construct the helm command by using these set values.
> For example, helm install --set key1=val1 ./redis

In your case this would mean

```
   overrideValues: template.image.tag=$(imagetag),environment.internalConfigMap.data.AZ_DIRECTORY=xxx,environment.internalConfigMap.data.MODEL_ID_SVM=xxx
```

Comment: Option 2 looks quicker, so can i write like this: 
template.environment.internalconfigmap.data: key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3

Comment: No, rather like this: `overrideValues: template.image.tag=$(imagetag),environment.internalConfigMap.data.AZ_DIRECTORY=xxx,environment.internalConfigMap.data.MODEL_ID_SVM=xxx` (assuming you want to keep the already existing override value that you had)